# If the permuted set of $(1,2, \dots n ) $ is such that sum of any two adjacent numbers is a square. Find the generalized form of $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

$ \text{Let}$$ P(n) \text{be permutation of}$$ (1,2 \dots n)$$ \text{such that if}$$ P(n)={a_1,a_2, \dots a_n} $$  \text{then} $$(a_i+a_{i+1})=k^2$$  \text{where}$$ k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $i \in {1,2,3, \dots n-1}$.$\text{Find the generalized form of n}$.

All I could do is to stare at the problem and try out some examples. I could not think of anything general about the numbers which obeyed the property.Here are two of the examples, for $n=17,16$:

${8,1,15,10,6,3,13,12,4,5,11,14,2,7,9,16}$

${17,8,1,15,10,6,3,13,12,4,5,11,14,2,7,9,16}$

Comment: Are there no solutions with $n<16$? There's the trivial solution for $n=1$. For $2\le n\le 7$, the only valid neighbour of $1$ is $3$ (hence $1$ is an end point), the only other valid neighbour for $3$ is $6$, and $6$ has no other valid neighbour, hence no solution for these $n$. For larger $n$, this is the problem of finding a Hamilton path in a certain graph

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well, you can get a solution for $n=15$ by just taking the one for 16 and ignoring the 16 since it's at the end. :P I haven't analyzed too deeply since I need to go sleep, but I'm pretty sure $10 \leq n \leq 14$ shouldn't be too hard to analyze though since 10 is an endpoint, and its pair (6) only connects with 10 and 3. I'll examine this one closer tomorrow if people haven't already.

Comment: For $n=8,9,10$ we have the pair $(4,5)$ that do not connect to any of the other numbers. So these $n$'s are out.

Comment: For $n=11,12,13$ we have the triple $(2,7,9)$ that do not connect to the rest.

Comment: Now that I'm back and more awake, I'll try to write a small program to look at slightly higher values and see if a pattern emerges

Comment: Looks like from the program that the answer to Hagen's question is "yes", and the next $n$ would be $n=23$ (with 3 solutions)

Comment: Hmm. After trying $n$ up to 50, I think I know what the answer's going to be, but I don't have a proof. For those that are curious, the ones we've mentioned (1, 15, 16, 17, 23) are the only ones below 25 that work, but it looks like there exists such a permutation for all $n \geq 25$.

Comment: One thing I did notice though was that the number of solutions for each $n$ gets pretty high; it's not like each of the $n \geq 25$ have only one solution.

Answer (score 2):

Working on a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576986/pairwise-sums-are-perfect-squares/1577022?noredirect=1#comment3210262_1577022) naturally led me to this problem. I believe some of the results I got there might be helpful. First consider the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. We can build an undirected graph over this set, taking the elements as nodes in the graph, such that $(i, j)$ is an edge in the graph iff $i + j = k^2$ for some $k$. A valid permutation is then a Hamiltonian path (not a cycle!) through this graph. Let's call this graph $G(n)$ in the following.

#### A Lower Bound on Edges

Let $E(n)$ be the number of edges in the graph $G(n)$. I will now devise a lower bound for $E(n)$.

First notice that adding $n+1$ to the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ introduces potential new edges to the graph: $(1, n+1), (2, n+1), \dots, (n, n+1)$. Those which actually become edges are the ones that add to perfect squares, which is exactly the number of perfect squares in the interval $[n+2, 2n+1]$. This in turn is equal to:

$$\lfloor \sqrt{2n+1} \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{n+2} \rfloor \geq (\sqrt{2(n+1)} - 1) - (\sqrt{n+1} + 1) = (\sqrt{2} - 1)\sqrt{n + 1} - 2$$

Thus a lower bound for $E(n)$ is:

$$\sqrt{1} - 2 + \sqrt{2} - 2 + \dots + \sqrt{n} - 2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{i} - 2n \geq \int_0^n\sqrt{x}\;dx - 2n = \frac23n^{\frac32} - 2n = n(\frac23\sqrt{n} - 2)$$

From this then we can calculate a lower bound on the average degree of a node as $\dfrac{E(n)}{n} = \frac23\sqrt{n} - 2$. Translating back to the original problem, this means that nodes in the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ have on average at least $\frac23\sqrt{n} - 2$ valid neighbours with which to make a permutation.

Furthermore, the distribution of the degrees seems reasonably balanced among the nodes. That is, no node is "hogging" all the edges to itself. This adds more credibility to the possibility of an "adjacent squares" permutation. To see why this is the case, consider a number $i$ in the node set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Every square in the interval $[i+1, i+n]$ corresponds to a valid edge at $i$, except for $2i$. As above, the number of squares in this interval is at least:

$$\lfloor \sqrt{i+n} \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{i+1}\rfloor - 1 \geq \sqrt{2n} - \sqrt{n} - 3 = (\sqrt{2} - 1)\sqrt{n} - 3$$

The $-1$ accounts for the possible squre at $2i$. The step from $i$ to $n$ can be justified by studying the square root function and noticing that since its slope is monotonically decreasing, differences are more exaggerated for lower values.

**Note:** This reasoning in fact can be used in the related problems for adjacent sums adding to cubes, hypercubes, fifth powers and so on. In fact, using integration to get a lower bound as above, we can always arrive at $E_k(n) \sim n^{\frac{k+1}{k}}$. Here I use $E_k(n)$ to denote the number of edges in the graph whose nodes are $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$ and whose edges $(i, j)$ are exactly those pairs of numbers such that $i+j = a^k$ for some $a$. That is, it is the graph for adjacent $k^{th}$ powers. It is interesting to note that for whatever $k$, the minimum number of edges per node is unbounded as $n$ grows. This seems to suggest that for every power $k$, and large enough $n$ (depending on $k$), there is always a solution i.e. a permutation whose adjacent terms sum to $k^{th}$ powers.

#### A Simple Case

We can do some impossibility proofs for small $n$ by forcing more than $2$ nodes to the edges (start/end) of the permutation. For example, take $n=8$. The maximum sum of $2$ distinct numbers less than or equal $8$ is $8 + 7 = 15 < 16 = 4^2$. So all squares in such a graph are in the set $\{1, 4, 9\}$. Now, look at the number $8$. We know that $8 + x > 1, 4$ so we are forced to have $8+x = 9$ and so $x=1$. So $8$ must be on the edge, next to $1$. Similarly, $7 + x > 1, 4$ and so $7$ must be next to $2$ on the other edge. But we also have $6 + x > 1, 4$, so $6$ must be on some edge. But both edges are taken up already, which is a contradiction. So there is no Hamiltonian path through $G(8)$.

Answer (score 1):

Poking around the internet, [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542045/1476062) links to [A090461](https://oeis.org/A090461) on OEIS, and the latter seems to indicate that this is an open problem.

Judging from the OEIS page (the Stack Overflow answer references it too), it is conjectured that there exists such a permutation for all $n > 24$. It also confirms that 15, 16, 17, and 23 are the only $n < 25$ for which a permutation exists.

Comment: And since I made the comment a couple weeks ago about the number of solutions for each n, [A090460](https://oeis.org/A090460) lists out the different values for each $n$, starting at 15.